# Save reactive table selected from dropdown menu

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am new to shiny, I sm trying to save reactive tables based on user selection from a dropdown menu. I would like my dropdown menu to have a list of reactive tables that a user can select then click the save button to save the table selected, this is what I tried but the seems the dropdown doesn't select the reactive tables

```
# Set libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

# Shiny app with two fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(

    DT::dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300), tags$hr(),

    selectInput("data", "data:", 
                choices=(df1(),df2())),

    tags$hr(),
    shinySaveButton("save", "Save file", "Save file as ...", filetype="csv")


    #actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    #create dataframe one
    df1<- reactive({
      df <- data.frame("id" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John","Dora"))
      df

    })

    #create dataframe two
    df2<- reactive({
      df <- data.frame("id" = 2:4, "Age" = c(521,715), "Name" = c("Hellen","Jane"))
      df

    })


    ##########################################
    observeEvent(input$save,{
      volumes <- c("UserFolder"="path")
      shinyFileSave(input, "save", roots=volumes, session=session)
      fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$save)
      data <- input$data
      if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
        write.csv(data, as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
      }
    })



  })
```

My end result should be an app where a user selects a reactive table to save from dropdown then go ahead and click save button. The reason I opted for this option is that I have more reactive tables generated in the app that I would like to save each on its own directory.

Comment: Couple of observations... First is you need to load shinyFiles library I think. Second is you are trying to call a reactive from your UI, which you can't do.

Comment: @– Carl Boneri  I have edited it and added the library, now struggling on how to use the reactive tables from server-side not UI

Comment: Have a look at the examples section of `?updateSelectInput`

Comment: @LivingstoneM As Carl pointed out, you cannot use reactive content in the ui, ui is meant to handle static content. If you want to use dynamic content, you have to use uiOutput("some_id") in UI and use this is server output$some_id <- renderUI({PUT YOUR DYNAMIC UI HERE})

Comment: @ Vedha Viyash Could you add that in the script? I have tried here but it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

I set the `selectInput` to list 2 strings as default data frames to be downloaded:

```
selectInput("data", "data:", choices=c("df1", "df2"))
```

This can be dynamically updated with `updateSelectInput` as mentioned in comments.

You can have one `reactive` variable to determine what data to view and save `df`. `output$responses` will show the table. Both this function and the `observeEvent` will call `df` to get data, and `df` will provide the relevant data frame based on whatever the `selectInput` is set to.

```
# Set libraries
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)
library(DT)

# Shiny app with two fields that the user can submit data for
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    dataTableOutput("responses", width = 300),
    tags$hr(),
    selectInput("data", "data:", choices=c("df1", "df2")),
    tags$hr(),
    shinySaveButton("save", "Save file", "Save file as ...", filetype="csv")
    #actionButton("submit", "Submit")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    #data will contain selected dataframe
    df <- reactive({
      switch (input$data,
              "df1" = data.frame("id" = 1:2, "Age" = c(21,15), "Name" = c("John","Dora")),
              "df2" = data.frame("id" = 3:4, "Age" = c(521,715), "Name" = c("Hellen","Jane"))
      )
    })

    #show selected data in data table
    output$responses <- renderDataTable({
      df()
    })

    ##########################################
    observeEvent(input$save,{
      volumes <- c("UserFolder"="path")
      shinyFileSave(input, "save", roots=volumes, session=session)
      fileinfo <- parseSavePath(volumes, input$save)
      data <- df()
      if (nrow(fileinfo) > 0) {
        write.csv(data, as.character(fileinfo$datapath))
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: perfect, This is what I needed